# match word list from a file and output remaining words

Tags: python, regex

I have two files. One with word list lets say a.txt and another csv file whose second row are words say b.csv . I want to check if any word from a.txt is in second row of b.csv and print only those lines which are unmatched. Total 3 rows are there in csv file.

what I have so far achieved is printing those lines which have word from word list. But I want exactly the other lines. Here is my code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('b.csv', 'rb'))
op = open('a.txt', 'r')
ol = op.readlines()

for row in reader:
     for word in ol:
         if word==row[1]:
             print row[0],row[1],row[2]
```

Now what do I make it to print the lines which aren't matched ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The least intrusive solution (i.e. keeping your nested loop) would be something along the lines of

```
for row in reader:
    match = False
    for word in ol:
        if word==row[1]:
            match = True
            break

    if not match:
        print row[0],row[1],row[2]
```

Or using some more Python goodness:

```
for row in reader:
    for word in ol:
        if word==row[1]:
            break
    else:
        print row[0],row[1],row[2]
```

The `else:` bit is only executed if the preceding loop ended normally (without ever reaching `break`).

As suggested by thg435, it's even simpler:

```
for row in reader:
    if row[1] not in ol:
        print row[0],row[1],row[2]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am quite amazed by the "else" being one intend backwards than the original "if" . Is it something usual ? New for me.

Comment: The `else` belongs to the second `for`: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: I see. Never knew this. beautiful lesson indeed. Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess you can replace all that `for` stuff with the simple `if row[1] not in ol` ;)

Comment: @thg435 oh... I should probably code more in python ;). Thanks for the suggestion, answer edited.

Comment: this is another cool stuff. Thanks @thg435 . and thanks m.buettner for the updated answer :)